# Why viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewWillLayoutSubviews is not getting called in view controller

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have a viewcontoller Called P. Whenever I rotate the screen , viewDidLayoutSubviews is getting called in P.

But sometimes it's not getting called in P and I don't why it happens like that and I don't know how to fix this issue.

Here is the scenario when it's not getting called.

My view controller pushes another view controller called A on top of P.

When I pop the view controller A and suddently I steer the ipad from Portrait to landscape , then **viewDidLayoutSubviews** and **viewWillLayoutSubviews** is not getting called at that moment. but when I change the orientation again these life cycle events are getting called.

When it's not getting called , in UI the elements are not arranged properly

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: “then viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewWillLayoutSubviews is not getting called at that moment.” Does the whole app rotate at that moment?

Comment: Yes the whole app rotates but I can see the eleements are arranged wrongly in the current view controller for example when it's on landscape .. the views are arranged like it's for portrait mode

Comment: Is this an issue for every app?

Comment: I think it could happen to any app.All we have to do is during push or pop just rotate the screenthis would happen

Comment: The issue never happens with A it only happens with P

Comment: “I think it could happen to any app.All we have to do is during push or pop just rotate the screenthis would happen” I think you should report that to Apple. If they don’t send you the event you should get, that’s their bug, not yours.

Comment: Is there any other life cycle event or delegate method that I can use for the similar purpose ?

Comment: you could probably try viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator